# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> Flutter Map not loading firestore markers

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The markers are not shown in the map

```
class NewMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewMapState createState() => _NewMapState();
}

class _NewMapState extends State<NewMap> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  Position position;

  Widget _child;

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  BitmapDescriptor pinLocationIcon;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _child = SpinKitRipple(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: index.isEven ? Colors.grey : Color(0xffffb838),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    getCurrentLocation();
    populateClients();
    setCustomMapPin();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position res = await getCurrentPosition();
    setState(() {
      position = res;
      _child = mapWidget();
    });
  }

  populateClients() {
    
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('map').get().then((docs) {
      if (docs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; ++i) {
          initMarker(docs.docs[i].data(), docs.docs[i].id);
           print(i);
        }
      }
      
    });
  }

  void initMarker(tomb, tombId) {
    var markerIdVal = tombId;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(
          tomb.data()['location'].latitude, tomb.data()['location'].latitude),
      icon: pinLocationIcon,
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

  void setCustomMapPin() async {
    pinLocationIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5), 'assets/images/pin.png');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(0xffffb838)),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: _child,
    );
  }

  Widget mapWidget() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
              zoom: 10,
            ),
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              _controller = controller;
            },
            compassEnabled: true,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values)),
        SizedBox(
          height: 26,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The map is correctly loading but the markers are not shown. The firestore do have data in the database that can be retrieved location is in geopoint datatype.

I want to display the markers in the map. When I go through the debug console I found

> *Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method
> 'data'*

error in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tomb` is already a Map<String, dynamic> field and it doesn't have any method `.data()`. To get data from it,

```js
position: LatLng(tomb['location'].latitude, tomb['location'].longitude)
```

And check you are passing valid `latitude` and `longitude` values.

Comment: thank you the error has gone but still the markers are not displayed on the map

Comment: in your code, i noticed that you are passing same `latitude` instead `lat` & `long`. `LatLng(tomb.data()['location'].latitude, tomb.data()['location'].latitude)` check and pass correct values and debug using logs..

Comment: i have replaced it with the solution you gave me 
considering my firestore map->1->location:geopoint data
I am really new to flutter if you can explain me more it would be a great help

Comment: i have checked printing in the console it returns the correct values its just that the markers are not displayed

Comment: that needs bit more debugging; could you please ask a new question?